# Obj-C createFileAtPath Issue - File never gets created?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How is it possible that the if/else in the block below continuously returns "No File Found" in this scenario? I've tested on the device on iOS 7 and iOS 8 and each time, the file fails to be detected immediately after supposedly creating it... stumped. (everything up to the placeholder variable is defined)

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docs = path[0];
NSString *imgPath = [docs stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images"];
NSString *savePath = [imgPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageEntity.name];
NSData *placeholder = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1);

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:savePath contents:placeholder attributes:nil];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savePath]) {
    NSLog(@"File found!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"No File found!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needs to create the directory in which you will save the file in first

Add the below line just before `createFileAtPath` method

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:imgPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
```